# How to create custom plots based on an office.js add-in for power point

Tags: powerpoint, ms-office

I want to create custom plots from an office.js taskpane add-in. I know that the API does only expose shapes and as such what I want to achieve is difficult. What are your thoughts on this? Is it possible to use something like HTML coercion or Office Open XML? How do add-ins like thinkcell achive adding custom plots to the presentation? I have once read, they wrote their code in C++. How would you interface PPT from there?

Would be very happy about any thoughts on this!

Best
David

I tried to use the office.js PowerPoint library but realized that they do not expose any plotting functionality.